# Scaled Axis when drawing circle

Tags: plotting, rescale

I want to draw a circle and two lines, which I'm doing as follows:

```
Plot[{}, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> {Red, Circle[{.5, .5}, .5],
   Red, Line[{{0, .993}, {.5, .993}}],
   Green, Line[{{.5, 993}, {.5, .5}}]}]
```

I see two problems:

- The circle looks like an ellipsis because the axis are scaled. How can I avoid this?
- The green line seems to be starting above 1 rather than at 0.993.
- Any better way to do this than with Plot[...], as I only want to draw things, without plotting a function?

[image]

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option `AspectRatio -> Automatic`:

```
Plot[{}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Circle[{.5, .5}, .5], Red, 
   Line[{{0, .993}, {.5, .993}}], Green, 
   Line[{{.5, .993}, {.5, .5}}]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

More straightforward way to get the same result is to use `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{Red, Circle[{.5, .5}, .5], 
  Red, Line[{{0, .993}, {.5, .993}}],
  Green, Line[{{.5, .993}, {.5, .5}}]}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: that looks great, thanks